# Is it possible to stay inside a click event call stack when using promise.then?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, html5-audio

The `play()` method on an audio element must be triggered by a user initiated event but it seems like the `.then` used in my click event breaks the call stack. I have to use `.then` in this situation.

The ng-click calls `open(file)` in its controller which is just a reference to `open()` from my "player" service.

`open()` from "player" service:

```
this.open = function(file){
  storage.getUrl(file)
    .then(function(url){
      audio.playUrl(url);
    });
};
```

`getUrl()` just returns a string promise.

`playUrl()` from "audio" service:

```
function playUrl(url){
  audio.src = url;
  audio.play();
};
```

Now I can `audio.play()` just fine from another method in my "audio" service that doesn't use any promises. Can I make this work from `open()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to stay inside click event call stack when using `promise.then`?

Not in this case. It would be possible if the promise completed synchronously, but usually promises are used for situations that will complete *asynchronously*, and that's the case here.

Instead, you'd want to complete the `storage.getUrl` part *before* the click occurs (preload it), so that you can then play during the user event.